# Mark Text in Command Prompt in Sublime Terminus

Tags: windows, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have been using [Terminus](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus) for a while and it's a great plug in. I would like to be able to select text when I'm in it like you can with regular Windows cmd window. But when I press `ctrl+m`, like you would do in Windows CMD, nothing is happening; I just get the new cmd line.